# Why is my text hyphenated?

Tags: theming

I have a text field. When I enter text in the CKEditor the words look OK. But when I look at the rendered page, it seems as if Drupal has split all word instead of put the entire word in the next line.

For example the word "Materialien" in the screenshot is split and this is not correct. I tried the CSS `word-break` property, but it seems that something is coming from Drupal and is breaking all the words.

[image]

Comment: There's some hyphenation library on your page. That no default Drupal behavior. Find that library and remove it or make it to ignore your body fields. Probably some JS library.

Comment: @leymannx thanks how to debug that ? it seams its from the german language please see words are all broken "Marc O'Polo Bril&shy;len und Son&shy;nen&shy;bril&shy;len" if i use english languages not soft hyphens. Actually al the website words are broken with german language.

Comment: Ha thanks @leymannx it was in my theme/vendor/haphynator.js i comment is , now we are gold :) . how to set yyour responce as answer also i want to give you billion up :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some hyphenation library on your page. That's no default Drupal behavior. Find that library and remove it or make it ignore your body fields. Probably some JS library.

---

OP found [`hyphenator.js`](https://github.com/mnater/hyphenator) inside `MYTHEME/vendor/hyphenator.js`.

To remove the library, find out where it got added to the site. `drupal_add_js()` in D7, or some `MYTHEME.libraries.yml` library declaration in D8. Or just from the theme's info file.

I'd recommend to fix the hyphenation and simply exclude it for certain fields. This probably can be done with only a few lines of custom JS. Find out how by visiting the docs of that library from the link above.